# java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading (...) Provider uri

Tags: android, android-service, android-contentprovider

I'm getting some reports about an exception that's thrown when trying to execute a query in a content provider. These reports mostly come from users that use Android 2.3 (at the moment I have no reports of this issue in Android 4.x).

The content provider is completely private, it is not exported and is only used in the application where it is declared, so I don't really understand why this SecurityException is happening.

My provider is declared just like this, inside the  tag:

```
    <provider
        android:authorities="com.some.authority"
        android:exported="false"
        android:name="com.myapp.provider" />
```

This is the query that causes the exception (modified to match the provider above):

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
cr.query("content://com.some.authority/something", null, null, null, null);
```

I tried to search about this issue but I could not find another case like mine. I also checked the documentation related to content providers but I still have no idea why this exception is happening.

I hope somebody can throw some light about this subject.

Thank you very much in advance!

PS. Forgot to say that the query is executed in a service that belongs to the same application as the content provider, but the service runs in a separate process. Anyway I also got reports about this same issue in another app, and in that case the query is executed in the main process, so I don't really think the process where the query is executed matters at all.

---

EDIT:

This is the full stacktrace:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.myapp.provider uri content://com.some.authority/something from pid=16201, uid=10139 requires null
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1322)
   at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:160)
   at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:114)
   at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.bulkQueryInternal(ContentProviderNative.java:330)
   at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:366)
   at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:262)
   at com.myapp.services.CustomService.onHandleIntent //-> THIS IS WHERE THE QUERY IS EXECUTED
   at com.myapp.services.BackgroundService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
   at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace. Are you sure that the `SecurityException` is coming from your code?

Comment: I just edited the message to include the stack trace.

Comment: The `requires null` bit is something that I usually associate with somebody trying to access a non-exported component. Have you tried reproducing the problem on a 2.3 emulator?

Comment: Yes, I tried to reproduce this error in a 2.3 emulator with no luck. Everything works perfectly.

Comment: I'm also getting reports about this issue happening in Android 3.1 and 3.2